# MtG Arena: Fifth card after draft or selaed

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

I recently played some drafts and sealed games in Magic the Gathering Arena and  was wondering what happens when I draft a card (or get a card in sealed) that I already have four times in my collection.

Do I get a wildcard for my collection, similar to when I open packs or is it "lost" after I'm done with my run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment, 5th copies of cards contribute points to something called The Vault, which requires 900 points to open.

Commons are worth 1 point, Uncommons 3, Rares 5, and Mythics 10.

When you open The Vault, you receive one Mythic, two Rare, and three Uncommon wildcards.

The Arena Devs have stated that they are seeking new solutions to the "5'th copy problem", so this is likely to change before the game leaves Open Beta.

[Source](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Magic:_The_Gathering_Arena#The_Vault)

Comment: Ty for the answer. Have they stated if cards from a draft or sealed go to the vault too?

Comment: @Shiffty I don't know if it's been officially stated, but that's certainly the way it worked at the end of Closed Beta, and they didn't announce a change.

Comment: It looks like your answer is outdated... Any chance you could edit to reflect the new duplicate protection? https://draftsim.com/mtg-arena-duplicate-protection/

Answer (score 5):

As of January 17th 2019 [5th Card protection has been modified fairly heavily](https://forums.mtgarena.com/forums/threads/44955). However the changes as they apply to limited formats (Sealed, Draft, etc.) are fairly minor. You will still see in your card pools cards you have 4 copies of, and be able to choose them as normal. 
Going forward, when you receive a fifth copy of a:

- **Mythic**, you will receive **40 Gems**
- **Rare**, you will receive **20 Gems**
- **Uncommon**, you will receive **3 points of [Vault](https://magicarena.fandom.com/wiki/Vault) Progress**
- **Common**, you will receive **1 point of [Vault](https://magicarena.fandom.com/wiki/Vault) Progress**

All of this will be applied when you open your packs in sealed, and after you finish picking your cards in draft<sup>1</sup>. The vault otherwise remains unchanged, it is still 900 points total to open and you will still receive 1 Mythic, 2 Rare, and 3 Uncommon wildcards. However since you no longer receive progress from duplicate mythics and rares, it will be slower to complete.

<sup>1: This timing makes things kind of interesting, as you technically have the ability to go craft a play-set of a particular rare or mythic *after* you drafted a copy but *before* you finish picking all your cards. This could be a (really bad) way to get a couple gems if you are desperate for some reason.</sup>